# Least Squares with Non linear models?

Tags: regression

If we select a model to our data of a kind other than linear i.e instead of the linear model `y =  ax + b` we use `y = ax^2 + bx + c`

And use the same standard process of finding coefficients (least squares) should we be able to predict the best parameters **a**, **b** and **c** ?

In the [section for Linear Regression in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Example), in the Example section, they actually do this, but do not call it non-linear regression, so I wonder this:

- Can we use least squares method from linear regression with non-linear models ?
- Is the selection of a non linear model (like in the Wikipedia page) called non-linear regression or is it called something else?
- Or what are they suggesting ?

Comment: Fitting y=ax^2+bx+c to data involves LINEAR regression because the equation is linear wrt the parameters a, b, c. doesn't matter if the function of the variable x is nonlinear.

Comment: @JJacquelin That is why I marked this as a duplicate (though I am not thrilled to have the closure be automatic). // Minsky, does the link answer your question?

Comment: @Dave will this method be accurate for finding the coefficients a,b,c,d...in any polynomial then?

Comment: There are legitimate concerns about numerical stability of solving for the OLS solution on a computer, but the math says that you get the exact right answer by following the usual calculation. I like the comment in the duplicate that the model just thinks the polynomial terms (squares, cubes, etc) are new variables and proceeds accordingly.

Comment: Interesting, however when I do this in libreoffice, I have to especify say X^2 as a new variable, like this `y = ag + bx + c` where x^2 is g, otherwise seems to get one of the x as parameters, or some strange thing. @Dave

Comment: I cannot comment on the specifics on the software you are using. However, that almost seems like the point: you tell them model to consider some `g` variable, knowing that `g` equals `x^2`.

Comment: Yes, I do not have a good math background and dont really understand the linked post, but thanks for the help here..@Dave

Comment: Actually think i finally got it, when we put `x^2` as `g` we can easily think also about x as `u` and then we have `f(g,u) = ag + bu + c` and then we will be fitting a plane to some extent. @Dave

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146842/discussion-between-dave-and-minsky).